# Why does Doctrine generate different constraint names?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony2 with Doctrine to generate my MySQL tables. Usually, Doctrine is able to update the database quite easily.

The MySQL server is on a linux machine. There is also an Apache running which hosts my Symfony application. When running `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` on the Linux machine Doctrine tells me that my database is up to date.

However, when running this command on Windows on the exact same Symfony application and connecting to the MySQL server on the Windows machine, Doctrine wants to change quite a few of the constraint names. It seems that it wants to rename all the indices:

```
DROP INDEX idx_2d91b64f56629d6d ON table1;
CREATE INDEX IDX_13241BA356629D6D ON table1 (col1_id);
DROP INDEX idx_2d91b64fbad26311 ON table1;
CREATE INDEX IDX_13241BA3BAD26311 ON table1 (col2_id);
DROP INDEX idx_bc100bf27dc308 ON table2;
CREATE INDEX IDX_8C245317DC308 ON table2 (col3_id);
// some more similar lines omitted
```

Why does this happen? I had a look at [how Symfony generates the constraint names](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/51074ffd4a4c6d1fa08ad9746098c482cc8c1ce8/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/AbstractAsset.php#L218) and it is using `dechex` and `crc32`, both of which should be platform-independent.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are multiple implementations of crc32.

Comment: @Flosculus Surely there must be some sort of standard since the PHP `crc32` function does not take any parameters to select the CRC algorithm/implementation. Since CRC is used as a checksum, how could e.g. a checksum computed on a Linux host validated on a Windows host if both are running PHP?

Comment: For both your linux and your windows installation you always connect to the same MySQL server?

Comment: @t.niese Yes. It is always the MySQL server running on the Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cause, but it does look like a possible cause:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php

In the red section, it states that `crc32` can return negative or positive values depending on 32 or 64 bit systems.

This is because of the range of a 32 signed integer: `−2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`.
If you take from this that `crc32` assumes to work with unsigned bytes, any value it produces over `2,147,483,647` will become negative.

Then `dechex` will produce a hexadecimal value based on the decimal value, negative or possible.

Comment: This might indeed be possible. While both operating systems are 64bit, I am using a 32bit version of PHP on Windows as the 64bit binaries for Windows are marked as experimental. I will try with the 64bit PHP on Windows and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. The 32bit and 64bit versions behave identically on Windows.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to compare the 32bit PHP on windows with 64bit on Linux if you want to clarify this.  Create a script with runs a crc32 on a series of strings.  Specifically you are looking for cases where on windows the result is negative.

Comment: I did some testing. As already mentioned by "jian at theorchard dot com" over at the PHP `crc32` manual entry the Windows version will always return signed integers. The 64bit Linux PHP does indeed return different values, however the output of `dechex(crc32($var))` is again identical for both 64bit Linux PHP and 32bit Windows PHP.